# Chrome developer tools show js file that does not exists?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

while working on a wordpress website I can see an JS error in Chrome developer tools/console . Dev tools tells me, this error is in file xy.js (which is part of a plugin with other .js files) and I can inspect the file in sources panel, see its content and so on.

Now I need to edit this file to fix the error, but the shown path of this file does not exist in my local filesystem at all!

Could a .js file be generated on the fly and then being linked by a path that does not exist on my local filesystem somehow?

Comment: Hi @alex999, are you sure that the file is part of a plugin? Could it be part of a Google Chrome extension?

Comment: What text editor are you using? You could do a global search for a function name. Are you using a task runner like gulp, grunt, webpack, etc? If so, that would explain why the file name is different. Also, try disabling your chrome extensions and see if the error still exists,

Comment: Hi,
the path to the .js file, shown in dev tools, is:
`https://devmachine.local/wp-content/plugins/search-filter-pro/public/assets/js/src/public/assets/js/includes/process_form.js`

That part: `src/public/assets/js/includes/process_form.js` does not exists in filesystem at all.  

Just a thought: could the path being displayed this way, because there is a javascript map file (just like SCSS map files)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok "problem" solved: dev tools is showing me the path of the original source file from a javascript source map file.  I was not aware of the option in developer tools to turn javascript source map files on and off.